# C# setting form.visible = false inside a method?

Tags: winforms, methods, visible

hi i have this lines of code that i cant make it work
the goal is simple setting the form1 to visible = false

```
public static void DoActions(string Cmd){

if(Cmd == true)
{

MainForm.Visible = false;
}
}
```

but i keep on having this error

> An object reference is required for
>   the non-static field, method, or
>   property

usually i set the called methond to static.. so the error will go away
but on this case how do i do it?

thanks for any help guys

> 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `DoActions` is a static method rather than an instance method, however `MainForm` is an instance field / property.  The distinction is that instance methods operate on an instance of the class on which they are defined, wheras static methods do not.

This means that wheras instance methods are able to access properties, fields and methods of their containing class through the `this` keyword, for example:

```
// Instance field
Form1 MainForm;

void InstanceMethod()
{
    Form1 frm = this.MainForm;
}
```

You cannot do the same thing from inside a static method (think about it, what instance would it operate on?).  Note that C# will implicitly assume the use of the `this` keyword in places where it makes sense (so the above example could have been written as `Form1 frm = MainForm`).

See [C# Static Methods](http://www.dotnetperls.com/static-method) for an alternative explanation of static vs instance methods (this is an important concept in object oriented programming that you should take the time to understand properly).

In your example you *probably* want to change `DoActions` to an instance method (by removing the static declaration):

```
public void DoActions(string Cmd)
{
    if(Cmd == true)
    {
        this.MainForm.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

This will allow it to access the instance `MainForm` field / property, however this may cause problems elsewhere in your code in places where you attempt to call `DoActions` from another static method without supplying an object instance.

Comment: Hi Kragen, thanks for the explanation. it now made me understand why im having that problem.. do you suggest i change my methods to a non static one?

Comment: @Katherina You can either change `MainForm` to be static or `DoActions` to not be static (or supply an instance when accessing `MainForm`, e.g. `someForm.MainForm`).  Which you need to do will depend on your application - its difficult to tell in this example without knowing more context.

Comment: Hi Kragen, thanks for the help , i can say now im happy i solve my problem. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set form opacity and showintaskbar property in property window:

```
        this.Opacity = 0;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is static - and so cannot access MainForm.
Make your method non-static if it is not required to be so.

```
public void DoActions(string Cmd)
```

{
    if(Cmd == true)
    {
        MainForm.Visible = false;
    }
}

If it *is* required, then create a static field in your class and ensure it is set before this method runs.